# adding Objects to a Listview - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I've an array of objects:

Tratam --> has String, int ect.. and a Date object.

I want to add to a ArrayList 3 identical objects of each with different values of Date..

I have scheduled the following code, but as result in the arraylist always add the objects with the last date.. For example: If the dates must be 3:05, 3:15 and 3:25, add the objects with the third value.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!

```
for(n=0;n<tam;n++){
    addObj(arrayObj[n]);
}


public void addObj(Tratam trat){
    Tratam [] arrayObj2 = new Tratam[3];
    Date date=trat.getNextTime();
    for(int n=0;n<3;n++){
        arrayObj2[n]=trat;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, interval);
        date=cal.getTime();
        arrayObj2[n].setNextTime(date);

        arrayListTrat.add(arrayObj2[n]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple check on you code tells me that, you are adding same object again in the list. That is why you are getting same time.

This is what I did to check that.

```
public void addObj(Tratum trat) {
        Tratum[] arrayObj2 = new Tratum[3];
        Date date = trat.getNextTime();
        for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
            arrayObj2[n] = trat; // I think this line is the culprit
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, n + 1000 * n);
            date = cal.getTime();
            Log.d("inTemp","" + date.toString());

            arrayObj2[n].setNextTime(date);
            if(n ==1){
                if(arrayObj2[n].equals(arrayObj2[n-1])){
                    Log.d("TEMP","$$Equal");
                }
            }
            arrayListTrat.add(arrayObj2[n]);
        }
```

Try this:

Instead of doing this.

```
arrayObj2[n] = trat;
```

Try to do like this,

```
arrayObj2[n] = new Tratum();
   arrayObj2[n].setNextDate(trat.getNextDate()); // In short rather than assigning object trat to your array object. Simply assign values.
```

This should solve your issue.